# Unable to start Informatica Server

Tags: informatica, informatica-powercenter

I installed Informatica server on my Windows 10 personal desktop but I have not been able to bring up the service. Everytime I start it, it comes down automatically. I look at the log and here is what it says.

---

C:\Informatica\9.6.1\tomcat\logs\exceptions.log

---

2020-02-29 00:02:06,141 ERROR [Domain Monitor] [NODE_10017] Cannot write node metadata to the configuration file [C:\Informatica\9.6.1\isp\config\nodemeta.xml]. Verify that the file is accessible and there are no problems with the network or file path.

com.informatica.isp.corecommon.exceptions.ISPException: [FrameworkUtils_0021] Cannot find [WORKGROUP\LAPTOP-HH4DEO09$] while applying read-write permissions.

---

C:\Informatica\9.6.1\tomcat\logs\node.log

---

com.informatica.isp.corecommon.exceptions.ISPException: [SPC_10013] Process for service _AdminConsole failed to start.

2020-02-29 01:54:31,346 ERROR [Thread 6 of 6 in DomainServiceThreadPool] [DOM_10055] Cannot start the service process [_AdminConsole] on node [node01_LAPTOP-HH4DEO09]. Detail Message: [[SPC_10013] Process for service _AdminConsole failed to start.]

I have given all permissions on the C:\Informatica\9.6.1\isp\config\nodemeta.xml file as well as its parent directory.

Please help me with troubleshooting this.

Thanks

Sree

Comment: Is ti 64bit or 32 bit Win10 ? As far as i know, 9.6.1 server is NOT certified to run under Windows 10.

Comment: Looking at the error, i would like to do this - run Informatica service as administrator and give it a try.

Comment: Hi...Its 64bit Win10. I did run start the Informatica service as administrator. It shows as running in the services window. But the errors in the logs are not changed
                                                                                                                              2020-04-11 15:00:37 ERROR [Domain Monitor] [NODE_10017] Cannot write node metadata to the configuration file [C:\Informatica\9.6.1\isp\config\nodemeta.xml]. Verify that the file is accessible and there are no problems with the network or file path.
com.informatica.isp.corecommon.exceptions.ISPException:

Comment: Could you please grant full control permission on INFA_HOME\isp\config directory and nodemeta.xml file?

Comment: Yes I have done that already Koushik. My user account Sree is set up as an Administrator and part of the Administrators group.

Comment: I am sure you took care of standard installation steps like - setting up environment variables, adding entries in PATH variables etc. can you check if you can run pmcmd, infaservice etc. from command prompt.